# How to test connect timeout on RHEL c/cpp application

Tags: c++, unit-testing, tcp, timeout

I have an application which talks to server over HTTP. I have written a code to control connect timeout (amount of time it will wait before server replies) . But I am finding it hard to generate a test case to test my connect timeout code. Could you please help me.

Basically, TCp handshake will contain 
Host A sends a TCP SYNchronize packet to Host B

Host B receives A's SYN

Host B sends a SYNchronize-ACKnowledgement

Host A receives B's SYN-ACK

Host A sends ACKnowledge

Host B receives ACK.
TCP socket connection is ESTABLISHED.

In my application, if server does not complete TCP handshek in x seconds, applications moves to next server. But to test this code, I need a server stub which will probably accept SYN packet from client but will not set SYN+ACK packet to client. Thus making client wait for server's reply.

Could you please help me to create small server stub which will listen to particular port but will not complete handshake.

Comment: @awoodland Could you please tell me how can I instruct iptables to drop all the packets from lets say 10.10.22.34 or just SYN+ACK ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you mentioned RHEL I think you're best off using `iptables` to help test this. For example you could call:

```
iptables -I INPUT -s hostb -d hosta -p tcp --dport $port --tcp-flags SYN,ACK SYN,ACK -j DROP
```

calling that before running the test (or even during it perhaps?) and an equivalent matched -X to delete it seems to be by far the simplest way of breaking a handshake halfway through.

Drop all SYN+ACK (warning, **WILL** break new SSH connections):

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,ACK SYN,ACK -j DROP
```

Drop all from or to 10.10.22.34:

```
iptables -I INPUT -s 10.10.22.34 -j DROP
iptables -I OUTPUT -d 10.10.22.34 -j DROP
```

Personally I would use the most specific match you can possibly write to avoid accidentally breaking remote access or anything else at the same time.

You could get fancier and use the `-m owner` match to only apply this rule for packets to/from the UID you run this test as.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I will check using iptables. Could you please tell me how can I clear this particular rule once I am done.

Comment: `iptables -X` deletes a rule, you basically just write the same as you wrote to add the rule, but use `-X` instead of `-I` (insert) or `-A` (append)

Comment: Got it. One more quick question, here hosta is client host and hostb is server host, right? I want to block SYN from server to client.

Comment: In the first example yes. It doesn't actually matter though, you can reverse `INPUT`/`OUTPUT` and `-s`/`-d` and use the "mirrored" rules on the other host though.

Comment: The `--tcp-flags` option takes two things, a list of flags to look at and a list of flags which must be on (or off). You can make other similar matches using that.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't rely on `iptables`, or any other tool for unit testing, as those tests would be too brittle. What if the IP address changes, or the unit tests are run on another machine ? What if the code has to be ported on an OS where `iptables` is not available ?

In order to keep the unit tests **isolated from the network**, I would encapsulate the socket API in a Socket class. Then I would have a `Connection` class that uses the `Socket` class. I would unit test the `Connection` class with a `TimeoutSocket` class (derived from `Socket`) that simulates the server not accepting the first connection request.

Your code should not depend on what's going on on the wire.